# Form validation using oninvalid setCustomValidity whith button run at server

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

I have a server side form that has both html controls and asp controls, i used oninvalid attribute to call setCustomValidity like the following:

```html
<form class="uk-form-stacked" id="wizard_advanced_form" runat="server">
<div class="uk-grid">
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-2 parsley-row">
<label for="lstNationalIDType">نوع الوثيقة</label>
<select id="lstNationalIDType" required runat="server" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('تاكد من اختيار نوع الوثيقة')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" class="md-input" tabindex="1">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-2 parsley-row">
<label for="txtNationalID">رقم الوثيقة<span class="req">*</span></label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNationalID" class="md-input" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('تاكد من ادخال رقم الوثيقة')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" runat="server" tabindex="2" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
<div class="uk-grid">
<div class="uk-width-1-1">
<button type="submit" id="btnAdd" runat="server" class="md-btn md-btn-primary" onserverclick="btnAdd_ServerClick">حفظ</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

When i click the save button and the select or the TextBox was empty the validation message appears but the button event fired and save the data with null values.

So, how could i prevent the button server side event when the validation message appears?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Page.IsValid`

```
 if (!Page.IsValid)  
             return;
    }
    else{
       //Do save action
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following:

```html
<button type="submit" id="btnAdd" runat="server" class="md-btn md-btn-primary" onserverclick="btnAdd_ServerClick">حفظ</button>
```

to the following:

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="md-btn md-btn-primary"  OnClick="btnAdd_ServerClick" />
```